# Number of partitions with distinct even parts/parts with multiplicity $\leq 3$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

I am supposed to solve a problem regarding partitions of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ into:

1. distinct even parts
2. parts with multiplicity $\leq 3$

I am supposed to prove that 1. and 2. are equal.

So I tried using the generating functions, and if I'm not mistaken they should look like this:

1. $\Pi_{k \geq 0} (1+x^{2k})$
2. $\Pi_{k \geq 0} (1+x^k+x^{2k}+x^{3k})$ or maybe $\Pi_{k \geq 0} (1-x^k+x^{2k}-x^{3k})$, if I want to distinguish the parts with even from the parts with odd multiplicity

But I can't see how the generating funtions have the equal series expansion. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence counting these partitions is [OEIS A001935](https://oeis.org/A001935). "Distinct even parts" does not mean that all parts are even, it means that even parts are distinct and odd parts have no restriction. The corresponding generating function is
$$\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1+x^{2k}}{1-x^{2k-1}}&=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1-x^{4k}}{1-x^{2k-1}}\frac1{1-x^{2k}}\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1-x^{4k}}{1-x^k}\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1+x^k+x^{2k}+x^{3k})
\end{align}$$
The last line is the generating function for partitions with multiplicity at most $3$.